Datagrid won't get updated when changed from ViewModel
I have a DataGrid where its ItemsSource bound to a DataTable. When I Update the DataTable, the data from the ViewModel gets updated but the UI won't. I already use INotifyPropertyChanged for my ViewModel.
Here is my functions
 private DataTable hariKerjaTable;
 public DataTable HariKerjaTable
 {
     get => hariKerjaTable;
     set
     {
         hariKerjaTable = value; 
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HariKerjaTable));
     }
 }
 private DataTable kalenderKerjaTable;
 public DataTable KalenderKerjaTable
 {
     get => kalenderKerjaTable;
     set
     {
         kalenderKerjaTable = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(KalenderKerjaTable));
     }
 }

private async void GetWorkingCalendar()
{
    HariKerjaTable.Clear();
    KalenderKerjaTable.Columns.Clear();
    KalenderKerjaTable.Rows.Clear();

    var data = new
    {
        month = Month,
        year = Year,
    };

    string get = await BaseAPI.PostMethod("calendar/select", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
    if (get is not null)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(get);
        JToken dataToken = jsonObject["data"];
        HariKerjaTable = dataToken.ToObject<DataTable>();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something wrong when retrieving", "Null", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in HariKerjaTable.Rows)
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(row["date_calendar"].ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(date.ToString("ddd\ndd"));
            if (!KalenderKerjaTable.Columns.Contains(date.ToString("ddd\ndd")))
            {
                KalenderKerjaTable.Columns.Add(date.ToString("ddd\ndd"));
            }
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(KalenderKerjaTable));
    });

    Debug.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    foreach (DataColumn column in KalenderKerjaTable.Columns)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
    }
}

This is my XAML
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding KalenderKerjaTable, Mode=TwoWay}" FrozenColumnCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
</Grid>

I tried to add Mode=TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to the XAML, but it doesn't change anything.

How and where do you update the data that you expect to see change in the view?

First of all, we should never declare an async void method as it opens the door for a lot of different bugs. The only exception are event handlers. Always return a Task or Task<TResult>:
// Serious code smell
private async void GetWorkingCalendar();

// Correct signature
private async Task GetWorkingCalendarAsync();

Next, the Dispatcher.Invoke is redundant: 1) DataTable does not extend DispatcherObject (it's not thread/dispatcher affine). 2) Setting properties that raise INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChnaged is never an issue as the binding engine will marshall the event to the correct dispatcher thread.
Also, you should use System.Text.Json API as it provides an asynchronous API: JSON serialization and deserialization (marshalling and unmarshalling) in .NET - overview
A TwoWay binding on ItemsControl.ItemsSource is without any point as the ItemsControl will never change the IEnumerable instance that is set to the ItemsSource property.
In general, a binding on the ItemsSource property should be OneTime (for best performance).
Addressing your main issue, raising PropertyChanged alone does not help as the instance is still the same. The dependency property that binds to the property will only update itself if the old value and new value are not the same instance.
You must replace the instance (the value of property that holds the DataTable) or reset it.
private async Task GetWorkingCalendarAsync()
{
  ...

  bool hasChanges;
  foreach (DataRow row in HariKerjaTable.Rows)
  {
    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(row["date_calendar"].ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(date.ToString("ddd\ndd"));
    if (!KalenderKerjaTable.Columns.Contains(date.ToString("ddd\ndd")))
    {
      hasChanges = true;
      KalenderKerjaTable.Columns.Add(date.ToString("ddd\ndd"));
    }
  }
  
  if (hasChanges)
  {
    // Option 1: replace
    KalenderKerjaTable = KalenderKerjaTable.DefaultView.ToTable();

    // Option 2: reset
    var tableTemp = KalenderKerjaTable;
    KalenderKerjaTable = null;
    KalenderKerjaTable = tableTemp;
  }
}


I use async void  to handle some of my  RelayCommand  like this RelayCommand(ExecuteSomething) which ExecuteSomething is an asynchronous method. Do I need to change ExecuteSomething to Task too? I have a constructor for my RelayCommand which receive Action<object>
